# Update the attributes read and read_at ONLY when the user clicks okay in the "confirm tag" (rails 5)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In this i want the attributes to update only when the user clicks okay in the confirm tag, if I use javascripts 'if-else' instead of ruby's 'if-else-end' it updates the attributes without any concern from the confirm tag. I am new to web dev ad rails 5. Please guide me through a simple code to achieve this.

```
# this is my create.html.erb
<h1>Notifications page </h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload =  (function popup()
{ 
    var s= confirm('you have a new notification, <%= @user.name %>');
    alert(s);
    <% if s==true %>

    {
    alert('<%= @user.name%>');
    <%=@user.update_attribute(:read,  true) %>;
    <%=@user.update_attribute(:read_at,   Time.zone.now) %>;
    alert('attribute updated');
    }
    <% else  %>
    {
      alert('did not read');

     }

     <% end %>
}

popup();
</script>
```

---

```
#my controller
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @users = User.all
  end


  **strong text**
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      var = @user.name
     end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems you are mixing the server side code to present the view to user and the  client side code after the view has been presented to user.
The code `@user.update_attribute(:read,  true)` will always be executed when server try to render the view if you use javascript if-else.
If you only want to update when user clicks confirm, you need to make an ajax request again to server and update attributes in that request.

---

Here is my implementation:
1. Client side:

```
    var s= confirm('you have a new notification, <%= @user.name %>')
    if (s) 
    {
        alert('<%= @user.name%>');
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: <%= update_read_user_path(@user) %>
            success: function(){
                alert('attribute updated'); 
            } 
        })


    }
    else
    {
      alert('did not read');

    }
```

2. Server side code:

   ```
   def update_read
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
       @user.update_attribute(:read,  true)
       @user.update_attribute(:read_at,   Time.zone.now)
       render json: {result: "ok"}
   end
   ```